# Updating Libgdx through gradle

Tags: libgdx

According to the Libgdx wiki, I should have a "gdxVersion = ..." line in my grade build file (I'm assuming of my core project). However, I do not. Is there some other way to update my libgdx?

build.gradle:

```
    apply plugin: "java"

    sourceCompatibility = 1.6

    sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = [ "src/" ]

    eclipse.project {
            name = appName + "-core"
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from the [wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Updating-LibGDX):

> Open up the build.gradle file in the **root** of your project, and locate the following line:
>
> `gdxVersion = "1.0.0"`

That means you should not edit the `build.gradle` file in your core project, but in the root folder of your projects.

After that you should proceed according to your IDE as it's described in the [wiki article](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Updating-LibGDX).

Answer (score 0):

Find out build.gradle in root of your project

```
allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = "XYZ"
        gdxVersion = '1.8.0'
        roboVMVersion = '1.12.0'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
        ashleyVersion = '1.7.0'
        aiVersion = '1.7.0'
        visRuntime = '0.3.1'
        visUI = '1.0.0'
        overlap2D = '0.1.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
}
```

update your gdxVersion with newer version.

Answer (score 0):

Usually updating gradle in the middle of a project or during an update messes up a lot of things. Just make sure your Libgdx version can handle newet Gradle versions. Most of the time you will receive a build error and will spend hours to fix that.

In my opinion, If you are not an expert just leave it be.